# Tell emacs not to create window if buffer is visible in another frame

Tags: emacs

Emacs creates a new window to show the contents of a buffer that is not visible in the current frame, like the `*compilation*` buffer when I use `M-x compile`. This works as expected when there is one frame. However, when I have the buffer visible in another frame (like with a multi monitor setup), it still creates the new window. To me this is kind of a waste of monitor space since I can already see the compilation!

How can I tell Emacs not to do this?

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`, providing a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: It still occurs when I pass `-Q`.

Comment: Just to be clear, when I say "window", I mean emacs window, not Xorg window. I'm reffering to the Xorg window as an emacs "frame".

Comment: Yes, please consider filing a bug report or enhancement request. Both are done using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Ok, I got that done. Meanwhile, does anyone know a quick elisp thing to put in my `init.el` to fix this?

Comment: It's complicated, but the thing to look at is `display-buffer` and `display-buffer-alist`.  That's how you can customize what happens (as far as displaying in a window) if a buffer is created or selected.  Also you can use `window-list` and `window-buffer` to query frames and windows.